# My usb stick is not mounting. It shows in 'Disks' though where I am able to format it but even on restarting it doesn't show up normally

Tags: command-line, usb, mount

It started when I found all the folders in my usb drive with their contents locked and unable to delete. I formatted the drive and after that it stopped showing up. It is showing in 'Disks' where I have formatted it twice more. No help.

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 03f0:4940 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
```

The USB is the Hewlett-Packard device.

`sudo fdisk -l` gave this output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00025dcc

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048 1945331711 1945329664 927.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1945333758 1953523711    8189954   3.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1945333760 1953523711    8189952   3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15514730496 bytes, 30302208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes` (no device identifier or any other info after this!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fdisk output shows that there is no partition on your usb device. your  usb stick is the 14 GB one right? if it is follow this instruction:

**These instruction will destroy all files on the device**

Open the device with fdisk:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

1. First to create a new partition table: Press <kbd>o</kbd> then press the <kbd>enter</kbd>.
2. To create a new partition: press <kbd>n</kbd> then press <kbd>enter</kbd> 4 times or set your desired value then <kbd>enter</kbd>.
3. Now we should select the partition type, press <kbd>t</kbd> then hit the <kbd>enter</kbd>, now you should select the partition number which we wanna assign a type. because there is only one partition just hit the <kbd>enter</kbd>. next you should insert the code of partition type, you can use <kbd>L</kbd> to get list of available codes. for NTFS insert <kbd>7</kbd> and press the <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. To wrtie the changes to the disk: press <kbd>w</kbd> and press the <kbd>enter</kbd>.
5. Now we should create a file system for the partition that we just create, to create a NTFS file system:

   sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1

Pay attention to the **sdb1**

Now your usb stick is ready to use again, you can use mount command to mount it or nautilus (or any other file manager which you are using will mount it automatically).

Also you can use ntfslable command to put a label on your usb device too.

Comment: I got till `Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 14.5 GiB.` After that i pressed w. But `sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1` is giving me the following error: `/dev/sdb1 is not a block device.
Refusing to make a filesystem here!`

Comment: instead of `ntfs` i used sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1` . What has happened is I am able to mount the 16 Gb volume but only 2 Gb of it is open for use. Everytime I click on 16 Gb, it opens another 2 Gb volume.

Comment: For the error you've got: */dev/sdb1 is not a block device*.  You should use **sudo fdisk /dev/sdb**,  I think you mistakenly used sudo fdisk /dev/sdb1 instead.

Comment: If  you want to create a fat partition when you choosing partition type select 6 instead of 7 which is the fat type code. If you follow the instruction correctly I think everything going to work ;)

Comment: Sure, I'll post the outcome. By the way, why is it creating 2Gb "loop" drives? Oh, I tried `L` but it didn't show partition types. Posting entire sequence in the main question for clarity.

Comment: I'm not sure, Maybe it's because the partition type is linux and there is no file system on it or there is but a wrong one. after following the instruction and creating a new partition, run *sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb*. you should have a new partition /dev/sdb1, then create the filesystem on it. if you can't see /dev/sdb1 then there is something wrong. If you like graphical program more than command line, you can use gparted to create a new partition and filesystem on your device. it's really easy to use and here is the manual: http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual

Comment: I have posted the outcome up there. Everytime after typing 'n', i hit enter once and it goes to primary or extended. After that I have no choice but to follow the ranges it gives, that is 1-4.. 2048 to.. etc.

Comment: Okay, here is the thing. I saw your output. first when using fdisk you should use /dev/sdb which is the entire device and when using mkfs you should use /dev/sdb1 which is the partition. second when creating new partition (n) fdisk will ask you three different question. just press enter 4 times without entering any character. then when your partition created successfully go for step 3.

Comment: Thank you! It's done. The entire 15.5 Gb is now mounted and able to make bootable drive. Thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome, I cleaned up my answer a little bit more.  If you like you can check the answer as an accepted answer. it will help others to find the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed the drive and re-inserted it after formatting? It might of unmounted after formatting. Or make a temporary folder called usb or something in your home directory and try mounting it there.

```
mount /dev/sdb/ /home/your-username/usb
```

Comment: Tried this initially several times. I think the error is more complicated. Thanks